# MySql help to write a query

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose i have a table with 3 columns like below

```
 ------------------------------
|id | recipe_id | sub_category |
 ------------------------------
| 1 | 80        | 2            |
| 2 | 80        | 6            |
| 3 | 80        | 3            |
| 4 | 82        | 1            |
| 5 | 83        | 2            |
| 6 | 85        | 5            |
| 7 | 80        | 10            |
 ------------------------------
```

How can i get the recipe id which contains both sub categories 2 and 6 ??
Is it possible to get it using mysql query?

Comment: Your id column is rather strange. And can the same subcategory really be associated with a recipe more than once?

Comment: yes.. the subcategory refers to the ingredients of the recipe.

Comment: So, carrots say might appear twice in a recipe for carrot cake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM mytable
WHERE sub_category IN (2, 6)
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sub_category) = 2
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b8417/1)

Comment: @Mr.Noob It does work with the sample data provided in the OP. Please check the demo I've set up.

Comment: Given the comments above, DISTINCT *may* be redundant - but there's still a possibility that the same ingredient might be listed more than once: 'and some more parsley for garnish', say.